# How do I determine if my mouse is over randomly spawning objects

Tags: python, oop, pygame, attributes

I'm trying to implement a game which allows for the clicking of randomly spawning circles, which give you points everytime u click on it.

```py
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

class Circle():

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, radius, width):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.width = width

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius, self.width)

    def isOver(self, mouse):

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if mouse[0] > self.x and mouse[0] < self.x + self.radius:
            if mouse[1] > self.y and mouse[1] < self.y + self.width:
                return True

        return False

circles = []

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

current_time = 0
next_circle_time = 0

run=True
while run:
    delta_ms = clock.tick()

    current_time += delta_ms
    if  current_time > next_circle_time:
        next_circle_time = current_time + 1000 # 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
        r = 20
        new_circle = Circle((255, 255, 255), random.randint(r, 800-r), random.randint(r, 600-r), r, r)
        circles.append(new_circle)
        print()

    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for c in circles:
        c.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if Circle.isOver(mouse):
                print('Clicked the circle')
```

However, when I try to implement the last condition, if Circle.isOver(mouse):...
I get this error

```
TypeError: isOver() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mouse'
```

Anyone knows a solution to this? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate though the circle objects, which are contained in the list `circles`. Similar as you do when you draw the circle. You have to evaluate whether the mouse is on for each instance of the class `Circle`, rather than for the `Class` itself. Note, `isOver` is a [Method Object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) and has to be invoked by [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects).
Since the method is called when the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs, the current mouse position is provided in the `event.pos` attribute (See [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)):

```
run=True
while run:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for c in circles:
                if c.isOver(event.pos):
                    print('Clicked the circle')
```

---

Getting the mouse position by [`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos) in `isOver`, is superfluous, because the current mouse position is argument to the method.
I recommend to evaluate if the circle is clicked, by evaluating if the square of the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) to the center  of the circle is less or equal the the square of the radius of the circle:

```py
class Circle():

    # [...]

    def isOver(self, mouse):
        dx, dy = mouse[0] - self.x, mouse[1] - self.y
        return (dx*dx + dy*dy) <= self.radius*self.radius
```

Comment: "You have to iterate though the circle objects ... You have to evaluate whether the mouse is on for each instance of the class Circle, rather than for the Class itself." I'm a little confused as to why uh my original code doesn't work, I thought that defining isOver inside the class makes it a class method, which applies to all instances of the class already? So wouldn't calling upon the class( and by logical extension all instances of the class) and asking the computer if its on any instance of circle perform that function.

Comment: @awesomelej `Circle` is not an instance object. `Circle` is just a class which defines the behavior of a circle. `new_circle` is an instance object of  `Circle`.  `new_circle` contains the data of a `Circle` object. All the circles are contained in the list `circles`. But the class `Circle` has not any information about a specific circle. Read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: @awesomelej *"[..] which applies to all instances of the class already?"* Yes the method. But you have to invoke it for each instance separately. The `Class` does not magically delegate the method call to all its instances.

Answer (score 1):

`mouse` is not defined when passing it to your function. There are other problems too but these are separate.

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for circle in circles: 
            if circle.isOver(mouse):
                print('Clicked the circle')
```